# Remove comments from beginning text file, in Ruby or otherwise

Tags: ruby, database, import

My problem is this: I have a number of very large data files (totaling several gigabytes) which, besides the actual data, include some commented lines at the beginning of the file.

So they look like this:

```
# This is a file containing data.
# Here's how to use it:
# ...
# Now, let's get to the actual data:
DATA DATA DATA
```

The task I'm trying to accomplish is to remove the comments from these files as quickly as possible, because the tool I use to ingest them into my database cannot handle the comments.

My current method is this:

```
# For each data file...
system "sed '/^\\#/d' #{filename} > #{filename}.tmp"
system "mv #{filename}.tmp #{filename}"
```

This works, but it takes about 1 hour in total, since the files are so large. My assumption is that there must be a more efficient way of doing this, since I know for certain that comments are **only at the beginning** of the files, so there's no need to search the entire file for them.

I don't care much whether the solution uses pure Ruby, or a shell command like the one above, as long as it works much faster than the current method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that very quick like this, i suppose you only want to have the # away, otherwise adapt but keep in mind that the written string needs to be exactly as long as the string read.

```
File.open('big.txt', 'rb+') do |file|
  loop do
    line = file.readline
    if (line[0]=='#')
      file.seek(-line.length, IO::SEEK_CUR)
      file.write line.sub!(/#/," ")
    else
      break
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, I want to remove the whole line with the comment, not just the '#'. And I do not want to replace the line with whitespace, I want to remove it completely.

Comment: No problem, then replace the lines with comment by dummyrecords, it is the only way you know, like this you do a inline replace, the original file stays intact, all other solutions involve the copying of the whole file which will always take some time. you can clear out the dummy records out of your database. how are the datalines structured ? in which db and how do you import ?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Your method is sound. Forking off a system tool is a great strategy for large files.

I'm wondering how such a simple transcode could be so slow.  Some things to explore...

- Are you sure that the sed(1) step is the slow part? If it's really the import that's slow, be sure that you aren't making each line into a separate transaction
- Are your files on a network volume of some kind?  And if so, could you run the script on the server instead of a client?

Comment: I checked the total folder size again, it's a whopping 90 gigabytes. So I think it's really just that. They are not on a network volume, and I'm sure it's the `sed` step that's slow. What I'm wondering is if there isn't some way to just cut off the lines at the beginning without rewriting the whole file.

Comment: No. The standard filesystem APIs only support truncating at the end. If you want to remove from the beginning, you have to read and write the entire file. However, that still shouldn't take an hour. More like ten minutes.